# Best way to convert a List<Object> to List<Object.Property>

Tags: java, arraylist

Consider the following use case:
I have `List<Song>` which holds an `ArrayList`.
I want to translate the above on-the-fly to `List<String>` which may be an `ArrayList` where `String` is used to store the name of the song (Property: `string songName`).
I am currently using the following method:

```java
List<String> songNames = new ArrayList<>();
album.getSongs().forEach(song -> songNames.add(song.getSongName()));
model.setSongs(songNames);
```

Is there any better (preferrably in-place) way to populate `model.setSongs()`?

PS: I think overloading toString to return the name might be useful, but I can't figure out how.
Oh yes, and I am also a beginner in Java

Comment: `model.setSongs(album.getSongs().stream().map(s -> s.getSongName()).collect(Collectors.toList()));`

Comment: As a beginner you are much better off doing it in the perfectly OK way you are now, than in a fancy way that you don't quite understand, so if you do use a Stream, make sure that you really understand what's happening.

Comment: I don't have time to write it up properly this evening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
final var songNames = album.getSongs()
    .stream()
    .map( Song::getSongName )
    .toList();
```

`songNames` is immutable in this case; if you insist in having an `ArrayList`, it looks like this:

```
final var songNames = new ArrayList<>( album.getSongs()
    .stream()
    .map( Song::getSongName )
    .toList() );
```

'In-place' would be this:

```
model.setSongs( album.getSongs()
    .stream()
    .map( Song::getSongName )
    .toList() );
```

And yes, this is contemporary Java. No external libraries used (aside, of course, `Album` and `Song`).

By the way, overwriting `toString()` to get the name of a song is not really a good idea (at least not in most cases). `toString()` provides the "string representation" of an instance – if its name alone really represents the song in your context, then you could overwrite `toString()`. But usually you expect something like "Song [Name: name, Duration: 4:33, Interpret: someone, …]" as the output of `toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stream in which you map each song to it's name:

```java
final var songNames = album.getSongs.stream().map(Song::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
model.setSongs(songNames);
```